# XSL 1.0 - can I replace (outer) tags when it contains an child tag?

Tags: xslt-1.0

How can I replace an (outer) tag when it contains a child tag?

Example: Line 2 matches: we search for the child tag that is surrounded the <tag1> tags.

```
<tag1> ... not-search-string ... </tag1>   <!-- 1 --> 
<tag1> ... <childtag>    ... </tag1>   <!-- 2 --> 
<tag1> ... not-search-string ... </tag1>   <!-- 3 -->
```

The result should be that only the <tag1> xml is replaced bij e.g. <replacedtag>.

Comment: Please also add your expected result. Could you share your own xslt until now?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mention an "inner tag" which presumably means a child (or descendant) element. An element is not a string and its existence cannot be determined by searching for a string. Please provide a minimal but complete example.  - see: [mcve].

Comment: your result does not make sense -- could you put it in the same format as the example input

Comment: Was busy creating a better example. The first answer below is a very good example. Only issue with the answer is that the child element could be at any deeper level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a good example to illustrate the principle here:

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <tag1>childtag</tag1>
    <tag1>
        <childtag/> 
    </tag1>
    <tag1>
        <notchildtag/> 
    </tag1>
</root>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag1[childtag]">
    <tag2>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tag2>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <tag1>childtag</tag1>
    <tag2>
        <childtag/> 
    </tag2>
    <tag1>
        <notchildtag/> 
    </tag1>
</root>
```

As you can see, only the `tag1` element that has a child element named `childtag` was matched and renamed by the second template. Everything else was copied without change by the first template (a.k.a the identity transform template).

Comment: Definitely what I am looking for. Thank you! Was busy with making an example. Question, what if the child node is deeper in the hierarchy? So a grand grand child?

Comment: You can change the match pattern from `tag1[childtag]` to `tag1[descendant::childtag]`.